# Why does Instant Run for Android Studio resurrect old build revisions?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-instant-run

Instant Run is a necromancer. It is supposed to apply changes instantly for debugging, distinct from recompiling the entire project from scratch which is a time consuming process for a fairly iterative development process.

Sometimes, it actually accomplishes instant changes as expected. In a few seconds after I am satisfied with my code changes, my application updates with the latest code running.

But then, it goes beyond that.

Sometimes, it says it gave my application the latest code which will be instantly applied to the part of the application I was viewing and debugging, but the application closes and restarts.

Sometimes, the application closes and restarts and shows up with no code changes. I can't trust the outcome, is my code wrong or is something else awry.

Sometimes, the application closes and restarts and shows up with old code. A build that should no longer exist. Resurrected from a cache graveyard that I didn't know existed. How is this possible?

Sometimes, the application closes and restarts and informs me that it is running an old version and that the only remedy is to use Instant Run.

??????????

How and under what circumstances does InstantRun do the above things, especially the part where it resurrects the old build?

Comment: Um, outside of the title, there isn't really a question here. I can completely understand venting about Instant Run (I keep mine disabled), but what exactly are you expecting to get from Stack Overflow here?

Comment: @CommonsWare the question is how and under what circumstances does InstantRun do the above things, especially the part where it resurrects the old build. I'll edit the end of the post to make it clear

Comment: I don't think IR has those "features", stinks like a bug to me. Consider posting it on the official repo (I tried to Google it, no luck, sorry)